# java - Split string by pipe '|' , ignore comma

Tags: javascript, string, jsp, split

I am trying to split a string, delimited by pipe character "|"
like so -

```
items.split("\\|",-1)
```

However, if there is a comma, in the string, the string is getting split by that as well.

How can I avoid this?

example-

input- something|1234|hey, how are you

expected result- split values by

- something
- 1234
- hey, how are you

  Actual result-
- something
- 1234
- hey
- how are you

Comment: It works fine for me. Error should be elsewhere, show us more code

Comment: `<c:forEach var="items" items="${data}" varStatus="status"> <c:set var="listItem" value="${fn:split(items,'|')}" /> <c:set var="field1" value="${fn:trim(listItem[0])}" /> <c:set var="field2" value="${fn:trim(listItem[1])}" /> <c:set var="field3" value="${fn:trim(listItem[2])}" /> <c:set var="field4" value="${fn:trim(listItem[3])}" />`

and you want to print 

`Field1: ${field1} <br> 
Field2: ${field2} <br> 
Field3 : ${field3}<br> 
Field4 : ${field4}<br>`

Where data is like - something | hey, how are you | 3456 | dummy

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use just the following:

```
let input = "something|1234|hey, how are you";

input.split('|')
```

Comment: Hm, seems like this works here: https://jsfiddle.net/aqn126jv/. Check where the split function is from. It might happen that someone overrode that.

Comment: This is similar to this question

[issue of JSTL forEach iterate from arrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947417/issue-of-jstl-foreach-iterate-from-arraylist)

However, there is no solution in that one either

Answer (score 0):

@Calculus Please use c:forTokens

`<c:forTokens items="$Items" delims="|" var="mySplit">
    <c:out value="${mySplit}"/></br>
</c:forTokens>`

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, I would like to use the split value as an array, since I will be assigning the split values inside the loop.

like in foreach, I can use items[0], items[1] and so on, to get the different items in the list and assign them to variables inside the loop.

In forTokens, I think we can just print the list as is. Is there a way, I can access each item in that list?

Comment: yes you can acces each value of list use instead of itrator

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Michail, should be overwritten somewhere else.

```
var item = "something|1234|hey, how are you"
item.split("|");
output>> ["something", "1234", "hey, how are you"]
```